# npm is not recognised as an internal or external command - install using nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I am trying to install nodejs and npm on my Windows 10 PC. Below are the steps I followed for the same

1. Downloaded nvm set up from [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#node-version-manager-nvm-for-windows)
2. Installed nvm install wizard using nvmsetup.exe
3. Opened command prompt and typed in `'nvm install v5.1.0`
4. typed in `nvm use 5.1.0`
5. typed in `node -v` and got the response back v5.1.0
6. but when I tried `npm --version` I am getting error saying npm is not recognized as an internal or external command

I updated the environment variables to set the PATH C:Program Files\nodejs. Restarted PC, and restarted Command prompt still no luck.
Really appreciate any help on this. thanks

Comment: Do you specifically need this `v5.1.0` of node ?

Comment: @yousoumar yes.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem after I switched from one node version to another using `nvm use ----`. Apparently nvm disabled itself at some point and using `nvm on` enabled it, now I have access to npm again.

The solution came about from checking this [page discussing the same problem](https://techbrij.com/nvm-windows-node-npm-not-recognized)

Comment: This works for me in windows 11. But when I use nvm on, it again switch to node latest

Comment: this is working win 10 also

Answer (score 0):

after execute `nvm on`, you will have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwKrf.png)

and make sure the target is valid
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJS9w.png)